# Customer Enquiry Form - Contact preferences

Tags: forms, mobile, desktop-application, customer

Q. Do customers like to have the option to provide a prefered contact time and method when submitting a customer enquiry form?

For example... 'When would you like us to call you back?' & 'How would you like us to contact you'

For - Customers who want to request a design consultation appointment

Who - Want to be contacted at a time which is more convenient to them (i.e morning, afternoon, evening)

On - The online appointment form

That is - Simple, convenient and informative

I've spoken to handful of customers instore, 7 out of 10 preferred to be contact at a time more suitable for them.

Before I present back to the business I'd like to have concrete evidence which supports introducing these extra fields on the online appointment form.

So on that note, what are your thoughts or resources you're aware that can help support what I'm trying to achieve other than best practices and personal opinion.

Thanks Greg

Answer (score 1):

This is best suited for an A/B test. Use your current form as a control experience, then create the new form you want to try out and use it as your B test. When you see one form perform better than the other you will have a more compelling report to present to the business.

It's harder for people to argue with the test data when they may have their own opinion/agenda.

Here's two good A/B testing options:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments

https://www.optimizely.com/

Comment: Thanks Seth - Unfortunately we have no MVT or A/B testing capabilities, the company I'm working for stop funding resources into UX, so we're limited to using free methods to generate evidence, i.e guerilla testing and online research.

Answer (score 1):

**Early Prototype Testing**

Since you have already spoken to some of the users, the quickest and easy way is to do the EARLY PROTOTYPE TESTING by creating paper prototypes and test it with users.

This will definitely helps you to get the statistics and help you to present the research and number in front of key stakeholders.

BTW, you don't have to invest much on this, but as a token of appreciation for the participants you can offer a coffee / pizza / burger, etc.